# NodeJS Post Request To Laravel Server Error

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, axios

I have two applications that are communicating with each other. One is based on expressJs , other is based on laravel. When  I try to post request to Laravel Server from expressjs via axios I face a connection refused error even though I can access the website using postman and browser.
[image: Attached is the image of the error]

Comment: try adding `http://` on your axios URL parameter.

Comment: I did , but it didn't work

Comment: The Laravel server is running on `:8000` ?

Comment: Yes it is running on 8000 port